# on the day of the deadline

Tags: time

I have term 31.3. and sentence "Teams are only allowed to have maximum of three games remaining on the day of the deadline."

I have question.
Deadline is 31.3 00:01 or 31.3 23:59?

Answer (score 1):

The *day* of the deadline is March 31st.  You can't deduce the time from that.

But it doesn't matter for the statement you provided.

Starting 12:01am on March 31st, you can only have 3 games remaining.  There is probably an additional requirement that at some time on that day, you stop playing or something similar.

Comment: I more describe situation. We should play 10 games. But we could dont play 3 games. On start 31.3. Our team have played only 5 games. 31.3. afternoon we played 2 more games. So on the end of 31.3. We didnt play 3 games.  Organizator say that we can not play 31.3 and we recieved penalty. And i want to know, if is rule clear?